# Faceting with multiple data sets in ggplot: how to set scales

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, facet-wrap

I'm trying to do something which seems like it should be fairly straightforward in ggplot. I suspect I am not searching for the correct terms and hence nothing has shown up. Basically I have data from one data frame, and map data in another. I want the facet_wrap function to ignore the data in the map data frame when determining the appropriate scales. Here is some reproducible code:

```
mapdata <- map_data("world")
df1 <- data.frame(category="A", lon=rnorm(20, -160, 3), lat=rnorm(20, 55, 3))
df2 <- data.frame(category="B", lon=rnorm(20, -130, 3), lat=rnorm(20, 52, 3))
df <- rbind(df1, df2)
g <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=df, aes(lon, lat)) + facet_wrap("category", scales="free")
```

[image: Points without the maps]
But now if I try to add a map to each facet, it uses the ranges from both data sets.

```
g + geom_polygon(data=mapdata, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group))
```

[image: Points with the maps]

How do I tell ggplot to only use the data frame `df` when calculating the limits? Basically I want to center the subplots on the points, but have a map showing to give a perspective of where they are. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm trying to think of something better than simply subseting your map data or using `coord_cartesian`, but I deal with maps that often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [issue](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/187) was commented previously, so that there is no native way of doing so. Subsetting is probably your best bet here. Add a category to `mapdata`, and `facet_wrap` is smart enough to separate limits for different categories.

```
mapdata$category <- ifelse(
  findInterval(mapdata$lon, range(df1$lon)) == 1 & 
    findInterval(mapdata$lat, range(df1$lat)) == 1, 
  "A",
  ifelse(
    findInterval(mapdata$lon, range(df2$lon)) == 1 & 
      findInterval(mapdata$lat, range(df2$lat)) == 1,
    "B",
    NA)
)

g + geom_polygon(data=mapdata[!is.na(mapdata$category), ], aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group))
```

[image]

Some additional work is required to make this look pretty (maybe a bigger area to subset?), but you get the idea.

Comment: tonytonov -- Thanks for this link. I'll play around with your suggestion and hope for a native solution in the future.